# Rename/change a tag - N1QL to SQL++

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I work for Couchbase, and we'd like the tag [n1ql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n1ql) to be renamed [sql++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql%2b%2b), please. The "N1QL" brand name is being phased out in favor of the more meaningful/standard name of "SQL++".

It's not *completely* rebranded in all our assets yet, and there's a lot of work to do on our side, but as a major indicator, you can see that our documentation now says ["SQL++ Language Reference"](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/index.html) instead of ["N1QL Language Reference"](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/7.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/index.html).

I'm not sure how it all works on the Stack Overflow side, but if a rename also retags existing questions tagged with [n1ql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n1ql), that works fine.

Will people trying to type [n1ql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n1ql) find [sql++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql%2b%2b)? Is there any sort of "transition" labeling (like "sql++ (previously n1ql)" that will be shown temporarily?

Also: once the change happens, I can rewrite the [info text for the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/n1ql/info) (which is sorely in need of an update anyway).

Comment: A retag request is correct if the desired end result is actually renaming the existing tag (creating a synonym from the old tag to the new tag can also be done at the same time).

Comment: There is a special syntax for formatting tags, please, use it as it gets them highlighted and linked to questions tagged with them when the post is rendered. The syntax is: `[tag:name]` for tags on the main site and `[meta-tag:name]` for tags on the site's child Meta. See the [formatting FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags) for more info.

Comment: Perhaps a synonym is better? Renaming it does not mean the old name immediately disappears from everyone's brain and developers can be a little... stubborn when it comes to letting go of labels that are practically embedded in their brain.

Comment: I think a rename *and* a (temporary?) synonym together would be good

Comment: When renaming/merging a tag, creating a synonym mapping the old tag to the new one is a simple checkbox that mods can click. In my personal experience, it's *rare* that we choose *not* to create a synonym. The only case where we wouldn't create a synonym is where we were merging/renaming a tag in order to disambiguate usage (e.g., the recent case of the [word] tag).  But yeah, when making a retag request on Meta, users aren't expected to know intimately well how the mod tools work. The mods know that. They're just supposed to present a good-effort proposal with supporting evidence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I've renamed the [n1ql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n1ql) tag to [sql++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql%2b%2b) (an action which affected 689 questions), and added a synonym that will transparently remap attempts to use or search the old [n1ql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n1ql) tag into the equivalent request on the [sql++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql%2b%2b) tag.

As a stop-gap, and to avoid possibly losing information, I've essentially copied the old [n1ql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n1ql) tag wiki over into the new [sql++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql%2b%2b) tag. But it would be great if you or another subject-matter expert could improve that tag wiki. Remember that when writing tag wikis (especially excerpts), the *primary* goal is to describe/define how the tag should be used on Stack Overflow and only secondarily to describe what the tag is/means. This is not the place for marketing information or to extol the virtues of the technology.